# How to change Spinner value programatically?

Tags: javafx

Say, one has got a `javafx.scene.control.Spinner` with following arguments passed into its constructor:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.1);
```

How now one can change its value programatically, ie. by using for example something like this:

```
spinner.setValue(10.0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of the value factory:

```
spinner.getValueFactory().setValue(10.0);
```

You probably need to specify the correct type in your declaration of the spinner:

```
Spinner<Double> spinner = new Spinner<>(0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.1);
```